# Access data store App engine from Android

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

It is posible access to app engine data store from Android without authentication. In web you can. I was searching but all tutorials speak about athentication but really a don't need this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes - just expose the data you want to expose via an HTTP API (of any variety, though something RESTful usually makes sense). It's not generally a good idea to expose the datastore directly, so you should write an API layer that suits the semantics of your application.